# Gstreaming - two web cams over tcp

Tags: linux, webcam, gstreamer, v4l2

I'm trying to **stream two web cams** on a single gstreaming command, I'm able to start a single camera with :

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=320,height=240  ! vp8enc ! webmmux ! tcpserversink port=8080
```

The idea was to start **another camera but on a different path**, could be IP or PORT, but by standards i tried only different port:

```
gst-launch-1.0 tee name=stream v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,framerate=12/1 ! vp8enc ! webmmux ! tcpserversink port=8080 stream. v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,framerate=12/1 ! vp8enc ! webmmux ! tcpserversink port=8081 stream.
```

**Using webm output and muxer is required**

But i always get this error: **Unexpected reference "stream" ignoring**

Following this pattern i found [here](https://medium.com/@petehouston/play-two-webcams-in-mjpg-format-simultaneously-using-gstreamer-2302ca91504)

```
gst-launch-1.0 tee name=stream v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! image/jpeg,width=800,height=600,framerate=30/1 ! jpegparse ! jpegdec ! xvimagesink stream. v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! image/jpeg,width=800,height=600,framerate=30/1 ! jpegparse ! jpegdec ! xvimagesink stream.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend reading the gst-launch syntax (https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tools/gst-launch.html) to get a better understanding of the error there. You create an element and give it a name: stream. Then you use this reference throughout your pipeline description.

Let's look at this part:

```
jpegdec ! xvimagesink stream. v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! image/jpeg,width=800,height=600,framerate=30/1
```

You are linking a jpegdec to xvimagesink and then you have a reference to stream right there. Then you are creating a v4l2src and linking to a capsfilter. The "stream" element you just referenced there in the middle isn't doing anything sitting there, not being linked to anyone. So this is invalid syntax and it fails.

**I believe you actually don't want the tee element, so you could entirely remove it and its references.** This is what tee is useful for: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-plugins/html/gstreamer-plugins-tee.html

Additionally, you could also have 2 separate pipelines, one for each camera. Doing it on one or two depends on how you want to manage and if they need to share some pipeline-related data, such as a clock. But that depends on your use case which I don't know deeply.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the piece of code you commented about is from the topic that i linked, its not mine, i just used it as a base to create mine

Comment: The sample you mentioned (the 2nd one). Also contains the stream element.